# How do I encode the url in below code?

Tags: java, http, request

I am looking for how to escape/encode the special characters when I am passing the url in Get request.

```
  public static void sendData(String strval) throws IOException{ 
  String doSend="https://myhost.com/views?strval="+strval;
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 try {
     System.out.println("inside try");
     URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
     System.out.println("builder="+builder);

     builder.setScheme("http");
     builder.setHost("myhost.com").setPath("/views?");
     builder.addParameter("strval", strval); 
     System.out.println("add param,sethost,setpath complete");

     URI uri = builder.build();
     System.out.println("uri="+uri);


     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri); 
     System.out.println("httpGet"+httpget);

     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
     System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

     if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println("responseText="+responseText);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     } else {
       System.out.println("Server returned HTTP code "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
     }
  } catch (java.net.URISyntaxException bad) {
     System.out.println("URI construction error: " + bad.toString());
  }
  catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("e.getMessage=>"+e.getMessage());  }

}
```

I am printing this out in the getRequest url..
The output string produced is like this: This is embedding some wied charactrers

```
    http://myhost.com/views%3strval=?strval=http%3A%2F%2Fcnn.com,http%3A%2F%2Fespn.com
```

I need to get the output something like this:

```
    http://myhost.com/views?strval=http://cnn.com,http://espn.com
```

Can someone please help me fix, how do I encode special characters like ? in the setpath?
Also 
Can you please help me modify this code.

Comment: I think in our decoded url are some mistakes. like here "http%3A%2F%2" it should be "http%3A%2F%2F".

Comment: Thanks! It was a typo when I pasted and edited here.

Comment: Np (p.s. you can also upvote comments if they help u)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `java.net.URLEncoder` for that.

Like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    final String encode = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.test.de/ -", "UTF8");
    System.out.println(encode);

    final String decode = URLDecoder.decode(encode, "UTF8");
    System.out.println(decode);

    final String decodeESPN = URLDecoder.decode("http://myhost.com/views%3Fstrval=?strval=http%3A%2F%2Fcnn.com,http%3A%2F%2Fespn.com", "UTF8");
    System.out.println(decodeESPN);
}
```

It will print you:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.de%2F+-
http://www.test.de/ -
http://myhost.com/views?strval=?strval=http://cnn.com,http://espn.com
```

**Adjustments you have to do for your example:**

In your Example you can print the decoded URL like this:

```
System.out.println("httpGet "+ URLDecoder.decode(httpget, "UTF8"));
```

**Alternative:**

Is there any reason for you to use the urlbuilder? You could also do it like this:

```
public static void sendData(String strval) throws IOException
{
    String doSend = "https://myhost.com/views?strval=" + strval;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try
    {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(doSend);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Server returned HTTP code " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
    }
    catch (java.net.URISyntaxException bad)
    {
        System.out.println("URI construction error: " + bad.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("e.getMessage=>" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Question is, how do I use this java.net.URLEncoder with URI Builder?  builder.setHost("myhost.com").setPath("/views?strval=");

Comment: Also, can you please point out how to do it in the above code I have written?

Comment: Do you need to use the url builder? Or is this "alternative" good for you?

Comment: I was trying to send a list of comma separated urls as URL parameter, so thought GET would be a good option. Now it seems like I am having issues with the special characters, I am thinking of implementing using POST

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your problem, but part of your problem is that you did

`.setPath("/views?strval=");`

when it should be

`.setPath("/views");`

I hope that helps you some of the way.